# use of double past tense in a sentence

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

The use of double past tense is always a bit problematic for me.

So far I have learned that when there is a **time reference** and **two actions happening in past** we use past and past perfect. The action which is more past or started earlier it takes **past participle**, the later one in **past tense**

ex: When I reached the station the train had already left

This is an example of an adverbial clause with a clear time reference. But my question

> 1) Is it possible to **use two past indefinite tense** in the same
>   sentence in a principal-subordinate clause structure?
>
> 2) Is it possible to use **past-past perfect time frame** in the same
>   sentence in a co-ordinating clause structure?

For example, if there's a sense of simultaneous action happening in the past, it doesn't make sense to use the past participle.

I can think of an example given below ( which may be wrong)

She emanated ebullience as she **learnt/had learnt** about her first rank in the examination.

My thought process was. Knowing the rank and being happy is a simultaneous action--> learnt
p.s FOLLOWING UK english

Comment: 'learned' not 'learnt'. But definitely the former in this case - you can't say 'as she' and mix that with 'had learnt'

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, yes this is perfectly valid.

> She emanated ebullience as she learnt about her first rank in the examination.

Adding the had would imply that she learnt previously and continued to emanate ebullience. I.e.

> She [continued to] emanated ebullience **since** she had learnt about her first rank in the examination.

I do believe you are correct to use *learnt*. Both learnt and learned are actually valid. Learnt is much more common in the UK. [OED](https://www.lexico.com/en/grammar/learnt-vs-learned)

Comment: Can you give an example of the 2nd case that I mentioned if it's possible?